# J2ME: how to define path for fileConnection

Tags: java-me

About writing on the text file, i have a problem to define the path. I m developping with NetBean and I put my txt file in the "nbproject" folder. I can read it by using "this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)". But for writing i don't know how to define the path.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the file in project folder, it is packaged in the jar file. The jar file is read-only. So your Midlet can not write into it. For security reasons. This is good.

If you need to write data, you can either use `RecordStore` or `FileConnection`.

`RecordStore` is portable. It does not ask for permissions. So for simple things, like settings for your midlet, this is the best option.
You can just define your whole file content as one Record.

For `FileConnection`, your midlet need to ask for permissions. But you have real files for example on SD-Card, there is no other way.